# Remarkable facts in pictures and graphs of the Riemann Zeta function on assumption that the Riemann Hypothesis fails

Tags: complex-analysis, graphing-functions, riemann-zeta

Few months ago I found in arXiv a remarkable paper that the author shares as [1]. In those days I read such paper and I tried understand the more possible. To me these lecture notes are a precious didactic resource at the researcher level.

Today I wondered what could be the more relevant facts that one find in those figures or charts with what the author illustrated his explanation, on assumption that (here we consider $\text{Im}(s)>0$, where $s$ is the complex variable) the Riemann Hypothesis fails (you can consider the scenarios more relevant, but I am interested mainly in the scenario concerning to that there are two simple zeros with different real parts on the critical strip).

> **Question.** I would like to know the more remarkable facts of the *X-ray* (see [1]) of $\zeta(s)$, or closely related functions (like its first derivative $\zeta'(s)$, the Dirichlet Eta function...), on assumption that the Riemann Hypothesis fails, as companion of [1]. Thus I am asking about speculative figures (you can add also reasonings with mathematical formulas) explaining in the spirit of [1], if it is possible, the most remarkable anomalies that one hope to find in similar figures for the Riemann Zeta function (or, if you need it in your explanation, in related functions to the Riemann Zeta function). **Many thanks.**

You can then add yourself drafted figures.

### References:

Currently you can find next article as arXiv:math/**0309433** on arXiv

[1] J. Arias-de-Reyna, *X-Ray of Riemann's zeta-function*. Universidad de Sevilla (2003).

Comment: For everybody's convenience, here's the link: https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0309433

Comment: Thanks for your attention @HansLundmark

Comment: Read the books. Look at the Dirichlet series for which the RH fails to see what $\zeta(s)$ would be if the RH had a counter-example for some $t <10^13$.

Comment: Many thanks for your advices @reuns

Comment: Sans le lien donné par Hans, ta question ne veut rien dire. En maths, ce qui est remarquable c'est ce qu'on arrive à faire, pas d'écrire des formules dont on ne peut rien faire et de mélanger des conjectures au hasard et sans les comprendre. Donc lis les livres, où tout ce qu'on sait faire y est expliqué.

Comment: Allô @reuns ? I keep thinking this/previous **Question** was interesting: what should be the X-Ray of $\zeta(s)$ (the study of its graph in the spirit of the course notes by Arias de Reyna) on assumption that the Riemann Hypothesis fails. Even the different question: possible pathologies in relation of the distribution of the non-trivial zeros (unconditionally, if Riemann Hypothesis is true or false) in such graphs. What are saying you? Good weekend.

Comment: Read the books.

Comment: Thanks any case, feel free if in next future you can draw a draft for some special case and add it as an answer @reuns